# how to setup up sprite classes without redundancy?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics

I am making a physics game using Box2d. Most of the sprites were created within the HelloWorldLayer.mm class, but now I want to create individual classes for each of the sprites with added functionality. How do I create these classes in such are way that I wouldn't have to setup b2Worlds, define ground body, set gravity, Debug draw etc. for nearly all the newly made sprite classes?

Comment: think about what code is common to all classes, add that to a superclass or as a component (see http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/06/prefer-composition-inheritance/)

Answer (score 0):

b2world must only single with same box2d world. So you just create it in cclayer(scene).